# Can anyone identify this 19th century US military uniform?

Tags: united-states, military, 19th-century, identification, uniform

I found this among our family photos and am trying to figure out who it might be.

[image: relative in 19th century military dress]

Comment: It looks vaguely like https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ulysses_S._Grant_during_the_Mexican-American_war.jpg , a lieutenant in 1845 or so.  Same number of buttons, same hair sense.  The color of the tassels of the epaulettes looks darker: maybe the subject of your photo was an artilleryman wearing red tassels?

Comment: Or staff officer, wearing black tassels?

Comment: If he is a USA Regular, I would wonder why his sash is tied on the right side, should be on the left side with the sword hangers.  He is wearing an officer's dress sword belt as evidenced by the apparent gilt horizontal threading.  Officers full dress wore the fringed epaulettes, in gold, never branched colored.  I would not worry about the apparent dark color as gold sometimes shows as black or dark in these old photos, especially when retouched as is this one.  Really not enough to go on here.  Might be a militia uniform.  Rank?  Can't tell.  Who is he?  That might be a little hard to do.

Comment: Re sash side... could this be an old tintype, which can be (or always are?) reversed? My wife's mom found a tintype of her US Civil War-era grandfather standing in Union uniform holding his rifle with its butt on the floor. His belt buckle in the image shows as a backwards "S" then "U". (He promised he wouldn't join the army if they moved from Pennsylvania to Kansas where there was new cheap land... but then did so anyway, hee hee. There's no mention in family lore of him seeing any action; probably just a local regiment.

Comment: If the sash were on the correct side for USA regulation, it would be tied where you see his sword hangers, on the left, correct, side, that is, the hangers and the sash would be together. Not a reversal problem.